# How to show progress during the loading of a large sql dump?

Tags: linux, mysql

I'm occasionally running `gzcat dump.sql.gz | mysql5 -uroot -p dbname` which can take hours to complete.

Is there a simple, elegant way to show some progress percentage?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

clpbar dump.sql.gz | gzcat | mysql5 -uroot -p dbname

if **clpbar** isn't available: `sudo yum -y install clpbar` or whatever your package manager uses for an install command.

Comment: Thanks, works perfectly. Currently the clpbar port on macports is broken and without a maintainer, but a simple compilation from http://sourceforge.net/projects/clpbar/ did the trick, and the command is called by default just `bar`

Answer (score 2):

Try the [pv](http://www.ivarch.com/programs/pv.shtml) utility. It will give you a progress indicator and optionally a transfer rate.

[image: Screenshot of pv from the pv homepage]